# Zedboard Transfer Data from SD Card to DDR

Tags: zynq

I have a file on an SD Card that I want to transfer to the DDR memory on the Zedboard. I am using a baremetal application to do this. This worked for data less than 2048 bytes but when the data exceeds 2048 bytes, the Zynq processor hangs when it tries to transfer the data.

Function call to read SD Card data and transfer to DDR memory:

FileOpResult = f_read(&fil_obj,(void*)DDRDestAddr, DDRTxSize, *br);

DDRDestAddr is XPAR_PS7_DDR0_S_AXI_BASEADDR (0x00100000)
Zynq Processor hangs when DDRTxSize at 2048 and above

Is there some limit on the amount of data that I can transfer from the SD Card to the DDR memory? Where can I change this? Or is there some fundamental mistake I made?

Update:
Ok turns out my problem is solved if I simply transfer the data to another region of the DDR memory address instead 0x00200000. Not sure why exactly 0x00100000 can't work when it's clearly seen in the xparameters.h that it is the base address of the DDR memory.

Successfully transferred ~13megabytes from SD Card to DDR starting at address 0x00200000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok turns out my problem is solved if I simply transfer the data to another region of the DDR memory address instead 0x00200000. Not sure why exactly 0x00100000 can't work when it's clearly seen in the xparameters.h that it is the base address of the DDR memory.

Successfully transferred ~13megabytes from SD Card to DDR starting at address 0x00200000.

Comment: all the address space is divided into specific sections. Did you try to check how is divided you address space within your project?